# How to disable the back&forward buttons in browser with vue-router in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I have written a project with vue3 and the router is below:

```js
//router/index.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import routes from "./routes";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  next();
});

export default router;
```

Now I wanna to disable the back&forward buttons in browser because of the flow control. I have added `history.pushState(null, null, location.href);` in `router.beforeEach` but this does not works.

How can I to fix this?

Comment: You don't need the `beforeEach` code.  When you navigate to a new route, just use the `replace` function of VueRouter rather than `push`.  See the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#History-Manipulation).  You want to replace because it changes the most recent entry on the history stack rather than inserting a new entry.  As long as you don't insert new entry, forward/back buttons won't be usable.